# How to validate a POST of a non standard action in Cake PHP 1.3

Tags: security, cakephp, components, cakephp-1.3

Using CakePHP 1.3

I have a controller with a non standard action name - say:

```
class WidgetsController extends AppController {

function modifyColor($id = null) {
// Some code that modifies the background color of a widget 
}

}
```

and a companion view  views/widgets/modifyColor.ctp

The modifyColor template POSTS to the action:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User',array('url' => array('controller' => 'widgets', 'action' => 'modifyColor')));
```

I get a 404 on the POST since the CakePHP Security component is trying to validate the form
and I would like to be able to validate the POST.

The only way I can get this to work seems to be to turn off POST validation

```
 if ($this->action == 'modifyColor') {
    $this->Security->validatePost = false;
}
```

This seems a bad solution.

How do I use the Security component on a non standard action?
allowedActions doesn't seem to work
Thanks
Danny

Answering my own question.

A. There is no problem with using any-named actions in CakePHP
B. A conceptual bug with CakePHP related to using the same function for the Form GET and Form POST

On the Form GET I had this:

```
    if (empty($this->data)) {
          $this->data = $this->Widget->read(null, $id);
    }
```

The Form itself had some code like this:

```
      echo $this->Form->input('id');
      echo $this->formView('Current color', 'CurrentColor');
      echo $this->formView('New color',     'NewColor');
      echo $this->formView('New background color', 'BackgrdColor');
```

Which was fine, except that none of these fields appear in the Widget model - and the CakePHP Security component interprets this as a sort of XSRF attack - since it is finding fields in the form that don't belong to the model. That's why:

```
 $this->Security->validatePost = false;
```

solved the "problem".

The correct solution is simply not to populate $this->data with the model in the controller action and handle the field assignments on the POST:

```
function modcolor () {
    $this->layout = 'app_ui_listview';
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
          $id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
          $u = $this->Widget->read(null, $id);
                 // Assign fields from the form to the model....


    }
}
```

Comment: You should use echo $this->Form->create('Widget',array('url' => array('controller' => 'widgets', 'action' => 'modifyColor'))); rather than echo $this->Form->create('User',array('url' => array('controller' => 'widgets', 'action' => 'modifyColor')));

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are trying to pass url and you are trying to pass the controller stuff too.

`echo $this->Form->create('Widget', array('controller' => 'widgets', 'action' => 'modifyColor'));`

or

`echo $this->Form->create('Widget', array('url' => '/widgets/modifyColor'));`

Comment: In the first version, the `controller` key will be ignored (only the `action` key will have any effect), the second version is equivalent to the code in the question: `echo $this->Form->create('User',array('url' => array('controller' => 'widgets', 'action' => 'modifyColor')));`. OR: unfortunately, your answer is not correct - the url key is valid, and specifying a url as an array is normal in CakePHP. Despite the status of the question, this one is already solved - see `Answering my own question.` in the question.